# Jinja2 encoding error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode, jinja2

I'm running app engine on my local machine.

I'm getting the following server error when trying to open a page.

```
  File "/path/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6/jinja2/environment.py", line 894, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/some_path/jinja/settings.html", line 15, in top-level template code
    <input type="number" id="timeToArchiveDropdown" name="timeToArchiveDropdown" min="0" max="48" style="width: 35px;" value="{{ timeToArchive }}">
TypeError: object.__new__(Markup) is not safe, use unicode.__new__()
```

not sure where to start with this. If I restart the server the error goes away for a while, then returns.

the problem seems to be the braces in `{{ timeToArchive }}`. What can I do to solve this?

note that I haven't been able to reproduce this error on my deployed system

Comment: Do you know what part of your code this is coming from?

Comment: yes its when jinja tries to render: `return template.render({})`

Comment: You should include the code where the error is coming from as well. Has this app been working and you changed something recently that it is now not working?

Comment: I have included the offending line in the question, the type error occurs at `{{ timeToArchive }}`

Comment: What is `timeToArchive`?

Comment: Use unicode to set variable/parameters timeToAchive